# Clarify read-only vs. write operations for Teams in documentation

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, documentation, stack-overflow-for-teams

The [API page about Stack Overflow for Teams](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/teams) says (emphasis mine):

> Starting with [the release of Stack Overflow For Teams](https://stackoverflow.co/teams), the Stack Exchange API exposes **read-only access** to data stored in private Teams.
>
> ...
>
> In addition to all **write methods**, the following methods (and their `/me` equivalents) are **not supported**

However, the API methods listed under [Articles](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/) on the main documentation page do talk about write operations:

> Add/Edit/Delete Only available for Business Teams via the [Teams API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/teams).

Can a staff member add some clarification to the documentation to what the actual situation is? Is it now possible to perform 'regular' write operations (e.g. ask a question) on Teams? Or are the Articles methods the only exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

API access and capabilities depend on the tier of Stack Overflow for Teams that you are subscribed to.

- Free - No API access
- Basic - Read-only API access
- Business - Read and Write API access

The above applies to both Q&A and Articles (only available at the Business tier).

A thorough re-write of Teams API documentation is planned for the first half of next year.